# How to write Linq Queries for CRUD operations using Entity Framework with Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework(EF) with Asp.Net for creating one website, In that I've Created the .edmx and .tt and DBContext.

Also I've done Get all records by using this method in my repo class,

```
    StudentManagementEntities _db;
    public Repo()
    {
        _db = new StudentManagementEntities();
    }

    public object GetAllStudents()
    {
        return _db.People.Select(s => s).ToList();
    }
```

I don't know how to do other operations like Insert, Update, delete etc.,

would somebody tell me the linq for that or else give me any examples link...

Comment: Brotip: That `.Select(s => s)` does absolutely nothing useful and you can remove it.

Comment: Just a tiny note for correctness, maybe you want `GetAllStudents()` to return `IEnumerable<Student>`, not `object`

Comment: Btw, a bit of a zen koan. I know all `Students` are `People`, but are all `People` `Students`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Add, Update and Delete Objects in Entity Framework 4.0](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=619)

// Insert

```
public void AddStudent(People s)
{
    _db.People.Add(s);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

// Delete

```
public void DeleteStudent(People s)
{
    _db.People.Remove(s);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

//Edit

```
public void EditStudent(People s)
{
    var people = _db.People.First( p=> p.ID == s.ID); // Replace ID with primary key

  // Copy all properties from s to people

    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: ... and `_db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Also depending on the type of context the method to add things might be `AddObject`. Personally I prefer the code first approach which lets you use more familiar methods.